# JS Add action to change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my site I have couple div with input, by default one of this radio button is selected and span above input have class `checked`

It's look like:

```
<label>
<li class="vir">
<div class="radio">
<span class=""><input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_4" value="34"></span>
</div>
</li>
</label>

//default option span.checked below

<label>
<li class="vir">
<div class="radio">
<span class="checked"><input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_4" value="34"></span>
</div>
</li>
</label>
```

Now for label where is span.checked I want add for element `<li class="vir">` class `test` so I add this code:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
$(function() {
  var x =document.querySelectorAll('span.checked');
[].forEach.call(x, function(span) {
  span.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('test');
});
});
</script>
```

When the page is loaded in default option class `test` is added to `li` but, when I click on another radio button class didn't change, in old `li` class is still, and in new chosen `li` class `test` didn't appear. How can I add this action to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to look for the change in the checkbox than run your code

https://api.jquery.com/change/

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ukbgqn1c/4/)

```
$(function() {
  $('span input:radio').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) { // if radio button is checked
      var x = document.querySelectorAll('li.vir');
      [].forEach.call(x, function(li) { // looping over all li with class vir
          li.classList.remove('test'); // remove class test from li
      });
      this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('test');
    }
  }).change(); // .change will run for the 1st time when page loads
});
```

better you can use full jQuery

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ukbgqn1c/3/)

```
$(function() {
  $('span input:radio').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) { // if radio button is checked
      $('li.vir').removeClass('test'); //remove class test from li
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('test'); // add class test to li
    }
  }).change(); // .change will run for the 1st time when page loads
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: I checked all your code, also those before edition. Didn't work. I think there is something not right with class selector.

Comment: @AgnesTom check the demo Links, did it work for you ?

Comment: It was work in jsfiddle, but not on my site. I don't know why. Finally I used this https://jsfiddle.net/ukbgqn1c/5/ Many thanks for your help it helped me find correct way to do that.